# Are there any direct buses between Dundee and Edinburgh Airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, scotland, edi, edinburgh, dundee

Next week I will fly to Edinburgh Airport (EDI) and I will stay in Edinburgh and Dundee. Are there any direct buses between Dundee and Edinburgh Airport or should I take a bus to Edinburgh city and then another one to the airport? If there are any direct buses, are they cheaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the website [Traveline Scotland](http://www.travelinescotland.com/welcome.do;jsessionid=B87098F764B128AF3E679EF1C253357D.sc3) there are no direct buses between Edinbugh Airport - Dundee and vice-versa.

Example: 16/5/2013 **Depart Edinburgh Airport** approximately 9.00 am gives you three options.

[image]

if you choose the 9.30am this will be your route, arriving at Dundee Bus Station at 11.32 am

[image]

If you then **depart Dundee** on 18/5/2013 at approximately 4.00 pm you are given the following options:

[image]

If you use the 3.40 pm departure your route will be as following arriving at Edinburgh Aiport at around 5.24 pm

[image]

Obviously this is an example, as I don't have the specifics of your journey, but no there are no direct buses for your specified route.